# Simplify $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin{(nx)}}{n!}}$

Tags: calculus, summation

Can somebody give me a hint about what technique I need to simplify this summation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin{(nx)}}{n!}}$

Now $\sin nx=$imaginary part of $e^{inx}=(e^{ix})^n$

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(e^{ix})^n}{n!}=e^{e^{ix}}=e^{\cos x+i\sin x}$
$=e^{\cos x}\cdot e^{i\sin x}$
$=e^{\cos x}[\cos(\sin x)+i\sin(\sin x)]$

Comment: Thank you very much, lab. You've replied to many of my posts and have been a great deal of help every time :)

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{n!}
&=\frac1{2i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{n!}\\
&=\frac{e^{e^{ix}}-e^{e^{-ix}}}{2i}\\
&=\frac{e^{\cos(x)+i\sin(x)}-e^{\cos(x)-i\sin(x)}}{2i}\\[6pt]
&=e^{\cos(x)}\sin(\sin(x))
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle \sin nx  = \frac{e^{inx} - e^{-inx}}{2i}$, decompose the series into two series and use $e^{y} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^n}{n!}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}Im(\frac{(e^{ix})^{n}}{n!})$$
You see that is $$\sum\frac{{y^n}}{n!}$$ and this is sum of function $e^{y}$